# Docker container not able to locate Zip packages?

Tags: docker

All Ubuntu wiley repositories are added to my Dockerfile, namely `main`, `universe`, etc. and are present in my docker image. However, `apt-get install` in the following Dockerfile is not able to locate any ZIP/UnZIP packages. Error log in the end.

How can I install these common zip packages? At least `p7zip-full` and `rar`.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
CMD ["bash"]
RUN add-apt-repository main && \
    add-apt-repository universe && \
    add-apt-repository restricted && \
    add-apt-repository multiverse
RUN  apt-get update -y && \
     apt-get upgrade -y && \
     apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
     apt-get -y autoremove && \
     apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install p7zip \
    p7zip-full \
    p7zip-rar \
    unace \
    unrar \
    zip \
    unzip \
    xz-utils \
    sharutils \
    rar \
    uudeview \
    mpack \
    arj \
    cabextract \
    file-roller \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

**ERROR THROWN**

```
E: Unable to locate package p7zip-full
E: Unable to locate package unace
E: Unable to locate package unrar
E: Unable to locate package zip
E: Unable to locate package unzip
E: Unable to locate package sharutils
E: Unable to locate package rar
E: Unable to locate package uudeview
E: Unable to locate package mpack
E: Unable to locate package arj
E: Unable to locate package cabextract
E: Unable to locate package file-roller
```

Comment: I'm surprised you get that far.  As far as I can tell, the ubuntu:15.10 image doesn't have an `add-apt-repository` command.

Comment: As @larsks already wrote, your Dockerfile can't work. Try removing lines about 'add-apt-repository' and about p7zip-rar, unrar,, rar because they haven't installation candidate in ubuntu:15.10. Doing that you can build the image haing other zip packages you listed.

Comment: I've added `apt-apt-repository` with some tweaks. I've lost ppa seach link to p7zip for Ubuntu wiley. But then need to know how to install `p7zip` from `zip packages` in dockerfile - Thanks

Comment: Formatting note: the triple-backtick markup from Github does not work here. To format code, just indent 4 spaces and that's it. I tidied up this post a bit.

Comment: Thanks for sharing know-how Dan

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Tried with this `Dockerfile` (your Dockerfile without what I told you in my previous comment):

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
RUN  apt-get update -y && \
     apt-get upgrade -y && \
     apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
     apt-get -y autoremove && \
     apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install -y p7zip \
    p7zip-full \
    unace \
    zip \
    unzip \
    xz-utils \
    sharutils \
    uudeview \
    mpack \
    arj \
    cabextract \
    file-roller \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD ["bash"]
```

It works and it installs zip and p7zip

```
$ docker build -t mytest .
$ docker run -d -ti --name mytest mytest /bin/bash
$ docker exec -ti mytest /bin/bash

 root@f01fc3456a2a:/# zip 
 root@f01fc3456a2a:/# p7zip
```

Comment: Hmm, so my issue was something else. That's why just by adding `-qq` why it could've worked ?

Answer (score 4):

According to Docker best practices

@gile's answer could be improved by:

- using apt-get update and install in a single layer
- avoiding apt-get
  upgrade

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache

> Docker sees the initial and modified instructions as identical and
> reuses the cache from previous steps. As a result the apt-get update
> is not executed because the build uses the cached version. Because the
> apt-get update is not run, your build can potentially get an outdated
> version of the curl and nginx packages.
>
> Using RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ensures your Dockerfile
> installs the latest package versions with no further coding or manual
> intervention. This technique is known as “cache busting”. You can also
> achieve cache-busting by specifying a package version. This is known
> as version pinning

> Avoid RUN apt-get upgrade and dist-upgrade, as many of the “essential”
> packages from the parent images cannot upgrade inside an unprivileged
> container. If a package contained in the parent image is out-of-date,
> contact its maintainers. If you know there is a particular package,
> foo, that needs to be updated, use apt-get install -y foo to update
> automatically.

This should be the same as @gile's answer with those best practices applied

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
RUN  apt-get -y update \
     && apt-get -y autoremove \
     && apt-get clean \
     && apt-get install -y p7zip \
     p7zip-full \
     unace \
     zip \
     unzip \
     xz-utils \
     sharutils \
     uudeview \
     mpack \
     arj \
     cabextract \
     file-roller \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD ["bash"]
```

*edit

The Docker best practices documentation has been re-arranged.

The advice remains the same. While the part of documentation that the above link anchors to now merely alludes to concerns between build cache and apt-get...

They have added a new section of documentation dedicated to this topic.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get

in short:

> Always combine RUN apt-get update with apt-get install in the same RUN statement

Comment: I no longer see this information at the link provided

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @DrewryPope.  I have provided an edit with a link to where this information was relocated in the documentation.